# Automatically scale video on import to sequence resolution

Tags: premiere

I have a multicam setup mixed with 1080p cameras and 2160p cameras (So I can zoom in on them)

But when I import the 4k clips into my 1080p sequence, they are "zoomed in 200%".
Is there a way to automatically set UHD clips to 50% size on import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by the using Default Media Scaling preference, which takes effect when you subsequently import media and/or add to the timeline.

**Edit** > **Preferences** > **Media** > **Default Media Scaling** and choose "None", "Scale to Frame size" or "Set to Frame size"

**Scale to Frame size**: Will resize the media clip *virtually* at import - such that when added to the timeline at 100% it fits the frame.

**Set to Frame size**: Will set the media scaling dynamically using the effects control, such that at 50% (in your example) it fits the frame. Importantly - you can then rescale the media up on the timeline without loosing the original quality.

You can also use Clip > Video Options > Scale/Set ... (with clips selected in the Media Library or Timeline) to rescale clips in the manner stated above.

[image: Set Import Scaling]